# How to link different parts of data blocks?

Tags: linked-data, outliner, data-blocks

If I have a text object that says "ABC" and I want another text object to update only what is written how can I do that using data blocks in the Outliner after effects quick can  do stuff like this really quickly. Is blender just as fast?

Sharing data like font type and what is written, but keeping everything else isolated would be uber handy.

Maya does something like this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrvzHLi4uI0).

I think blender might be able to do it faster, because even the demonstrator is wrestling with what he is seeing on screen in Maya.

I would like to see if it was possible without "animation nodes" or any add-ons in Blender.

Hoping to share this with the community in a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Text and type ABC in edit mode, then create another text, go to the properties window, text panel: the first tab will show a dropdown menu with two datablock, named "text" and "text.001".

Just assign the first ("text", wich is "ABC") to the second object and every time you edit the "ABC" text, it will update all the objects, as they refere to the same object data.

Comment: While this will be obvious to many, it's worth mentioning that [Alt] [D] will make a Linked Duplicate of the Text Object. But yeah - understanding what's happening with the Datablock relationships (as your answer describes) is the most important thing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this better explains it one text would read the text geometry as both while the other would read the same.

I would like to be able to copy part of a datablock not the whole datablock. I hope this can clear up any miscommunication.

Is this possible simply?

[image]